# Prevent Protractor from compiling angular code

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-e2e

the Protractor tests appear to be slow, it's because Angular has to compile the code every time.

I tried `ng e2e -s false`, I read that on net. But it is giving error `ng e2e -s false`.

Please help, how can I load `e2e` faster.

Comment: Protractor tests should be fast, you may have some wrong configuration. try to check if there is any logs to verify if any error you have.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue, try the following instead

```
ng e2e --webdriver-update=false --devServerTarget=''
```

my current ng --version yields

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.1
Node: 10.14.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.1.1
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, http, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.1
@angular/fire                     5.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.1
@schematics/update                0.11.1
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.3
webpack                           4.19.1
```

See also the following thread

> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10741